# AngularJS use variable in ng-* statements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use AngularJS 1.5, and I want to use ng-repeat to build a form.

Now, I have in my code :

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': Form.field1.$dirty && Form.field1.$invalid}">
     <label class="control-label"> Label 1 required <span class="symbol required"></span> </label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.field1" ng-required="currentStep == 2" ng-blur="function1()">
     <span class="error" ng-if="Form.field1.$dirty && Form.field1.$error.required">Field required !</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label"> Label 2 not required </label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.field2">
 </div>
 ....
```

I want to use an array to buid my form like that :

```
$scope.myForm= [{
    'type': 'text',
    'name': 'field1',
    'required': true,
    'label': 'My field 1',
    'ng': [{'ng-blur': 'function1'}]
}, {
    'type': 'text',
    'name': 'field2',
    'required': false,
    'label': 'My field 2',
}];
```

So I tried something like that :

```
<div ng-repeat="field in myForm" class="form-group {field.name}}" ng-class="{'has-error': Form.{{ field.name }}.$dirty && Form.{{ field.name }}.$invalid}">
    <label class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="{{ field.name }}" ng-model="adherent.{{ field.name }}" ng-required="currentStep == 2">
    <span ng-if="{{ field.required }}" class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.numeroSecuriteSociale.$dirty && Form.numeroSecuriteSociale.$error.required">Field required !</span>
</div>
```

But of course I got a syntax error... Do I have to create a directive ? or to use ng-init ?

Comment: I did this once before on a large form and it was really difficult to maintain the code once the fields started to interact with each other. 

Initially I thought it would be cleaner to have the fields come from an Array, but looking back don't think the added complexity was worth the small reduction in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `ngInit`!!! It has two very specific uses and really shouldn't be used for anything else: [have a look](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.9/docs/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

You actually have some syntax errors:

Missing second opening curly brace:

```
class="form-group {field.name}}"
```

Also, I'm pretty sure this is not going to work:

```
ng-class="{'has-error': Form.{{ field.name }}.$dirty ...
```

`ngClass` is not setup to do interpolation in the way you are trying to use it. You are basically writing this:

```
ng-class="{'has-error': Form."exampleFieldName".$dirty
```

And that is never going to work.

You are better off writing a directive or a component and using ng-repeat with that. Using this approach makes way more sense and is much easier to implement. Ultimately you want something like this:

```
$scope.myForm= [{
  'type': 'text',
  'name': 'field1',
  'required': true,
  'label': 'My field 1',
  'ng': [{'ng-blur': 'function1'}],
  model: {}
}, {
  'type': 'text',
  'name': 'field2',
  'required': false,
  'label': 'My field 2',
  model: {}
}];

<my-form-field field="field" ng-model="field.model" ng-repeat="field in myForm"></my-form-field>
```

See how easy that is to write and read? About actually writing the directive/component... that could prove to be quite a challenge. I'm sure if you do some Google-ing you will find someone that has written a blog on this exact subject.

Comment: Yes you're right. I will take a look to directive and try to understand how it works. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different object-syntax for your ng-model. This should do the job:

```
ng-model="adherent[field.name]"
```